# Change event of select does not work on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a widget using the example given by jquery on combobox. I am having a hard time designing it so I created/modified the example.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LjVWQ/)

When I change the value using the original control, the change event is working but it is not on the other one. I don't understand why the change event does not trigger on the new control that I created where in fact, it both changes the value itself.

I found out that I can trigger some codes on line autocompleteselect (ln38)

```
autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
    ui.item.option.selected = true;
    this._trigger("select", event, {
        item: ui.item.option
    });
    // alert('I can put some codes here');
},
```

But I want to trigger the change event of the selector so that it would be a lot easier for the users to run scripts.

Any idea how to fix this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the value of the source element is done programatically using a script which will not fire the change event(it is fired only if the change was done by a user event).

One possible solution is to trigger a change event like

```
this.element.trigger("change", event, {
    item: ui.item.option
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aYd4k/)